# macOS : Correct programmatic way to determine volume info

Tags: c++, macos, filesystems, posix, macos-high-sierra

Currently we use stafs  to determine the information about the filesystem volume we are on.

```
#include <string>  
#include <iostream>  
#include <sys/mount.h>  
#include <sys/param.h>  

void statFileSys(const std::string f)  
{  
    struct statfs fileStat;  
    if(statfs(f.data(),&fileStat) == 0)  
    {  
        std::cout << "File type: " << fileStat.f_type <<'\n';  
        std::cout << "File system name: "<<fileStat.f_fstypename << '\n';  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        std::cout << "statfs failed !!!"<<std::endl;  
    }  
}  

int main()  
{  
    statFileSys("/some/network/path");  
    statFileSys("/tmp");  

    return 0;  
}
```

We rely on

```
f_type
```

value to make decisions based on whether its HFS+ or APFS or network file system.

However, we are seeing following weird output on three different macOS systems for above small standalone reproducible code.

```
1]
macOS 10.12 + HFS+
File type: 25
File system name: autofs
File type: 23
File system name: hfs

2]
macOS 10.13 (beta) + HFS+
File type: 24
File system name: autofs
File type: 23
File system name: hfs

3]
macOS 10.13 (beta) + APFS
File type: 25
File system name: autofs
File type: 24
File system name: apfs
```

For `2]` we get the `f_type` value for the network path (autofs) as 24 and while in `3]` we get `f_type` as 24 for APFS whch doesnt seem consistent.

This brings us to the qustion, is `statfs` the correct programmatic way to find the filesystem volume info on macOS ?

If its not, then what would be the right way to do the same ?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `f_type` instead of `f_fstypename[]` for decision making purposes?

Comment: I haven't verified this for certain yet, but my guess so far is that f_type is giving a partition number or something similar, which can be different based on disk mounting processes.  This would mean you probably couldn't use it except as a comparison to make sure its the same partition.  Again this is all a theory but check this page and check the numbers the terminal gives vs your program: https://ss64.com/osx/diskutil.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [documentation for vfs_filetype](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1523418-vfs_typenum?language=objc), which is returned by vfs_statfs(), Apple regards the filesystem type numbers as an archaic mechanism. While this is not definitive for statfs(), vfs_statfs() is better documented:

> Filesystem type numbers are an old construct; most filesystems
> just get a number assigned based on the order in which they are
> registered with the system.

As filesystem type numbers are now assigned at runtime in recent versions of MacOS, you *must* use `f_fstypename` to determine the type. You will note that in the signature for AppKit's [`getFileSystemInfoForPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1526987-getfilesysteminfoforpath?language=objc) method that filesystem type is represented as a string there as well. It seems the most official you're going to get is Apple's own API.

```
#include <string>  
#include <iostream>  
#include <sys/mount.h>  
#include <sys/param.h>  

void statFileSys(const std::string f)  
{  
    struct statfs fileStat;  
    if(statfs(f.data(),&fileStat) == 0)  
    {  
        if(!strcmp(fileStat.f_fstypename, "apfs") )
            std::cout << "File system is APFS" << std::endl;
        else if(!strcmp(fileStat.f_fstypename, "hfs") )
            std::cout << "File system is HFS+" << std::endl;
        else if(!strcmp(fileStat.f_fstypename, "nfs") )
            std::cout << "File system is NFS" << std::endl;
        else if(!strcmp(fileStat.f_fstypename, "cd9660") )
            std::cout << "File system is CD-ROM" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "We weren't looking for a " 
                << fileStat.f_fstypename << " were we?" << std::endl;
    }  
    else  
    {  
        std::cout << "statfs failed !!!" << std::endl;  
    }  
}  

int main()  
{  
    statFileSys("/some/network/path");  
    statFileSys("/tmp");  

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: no one commented about 'Suggested edit queue is full' and there it needs a little editing? For instance, 'std::count' is a function to be made yet ?

Comment: No idea what you're talking about here. There is no "std::count".

Comment: mentioned about this line, std::count << "We weren't looking for a "  , a spelling mistake and closing brackets on the 'if' statements.