# How can I display Disk File System Type (HFS+, APFS etc) using Swift

Tags: swift, file

I'm trying to display data on available disks. One of the things I want to display is its File System Type. What should I add to this piece of code:\

```
extension FileManager {
    static var mountedVolumes: [URL] {
        (FileManager.default.mountedVolumeURLs(includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil) ?? []).filter({$0.path.hasPrefix("/Volumes/")})
    }
}

extension URL {
    var volumeTotalCapacity: Int? {
        (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.volumeTotalCapacityKey]))?.volumeTotalCapacity
    }
    var volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage: Int64? {
        (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey]))?.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage
    }
    var name: String? {
        (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.nameKey]))?.name
    }
}

for url in FileManager.mountedVolumes {
    print("")
    print(url.name ?? "Untitled")
    print("Capacity:", url.volumeTotalCapacity ?? "nil")
    print("Available:", url.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage ?? "nil")
    print("File System type:", url.isFileURL)
    //print("File System Type:", )
}
```

Comment: What is `FileManager.mountedVolumes`? Is that returning a `URL`, then what are the other: `volumeTotalCapacity`, etc? I don't see them in the documentation.

Comment: @Larme this is a url resource key value

Comment: @Larme Hey! I updated the question adding used extensions

Comment: @LeoDabus That's what I guessed, but there was maybe too much "shortcuts" through custom extension on `URL`/`FileManager`, which might be helpful. It's C++, but might worth a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345265/macos-correct-programmatic-way-to-determine-volume-info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the URLResourceKey `volumeLocalizedFormatDescriptionKey` to get the disk file system

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let resourceKeys: [URLResourceKey] = [.volumeNameKey, .volumeLocalizedFormatDescriptionKey]

if let volumes = fileManager.mountedVolumeURLs(includingResourceValuesForKeys: resourceKeys, options: .skipHiddenVolumes) {
    for volume in volumes {
        if let resources = try? volume.resourceValues(forKeys: Set(resourceKeys)), 
           let name = resources.volumeName, 
           let format = resources.volumeLocalizedFormatDescription {
            print("\(name), format: \(format)")
        }
    }
}
```

Example from my machine with an external drive and a SD card attached

> Macintosh HD, format: APFS
> Bilder-Arkiv, format: Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
> LEICA M9, format: MS-DOS (FAT32)

Comment: no need to pass the keys for `mountedVolumeURLs`. You can simply pass nil. Btw Don't force try. I would do something like `extension URL {` `var volumeFormat: String? {` `(try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.volumeLocalizedFormatDescriptionKey]))?.volumeLocalizedFormatDescription` `}` `}`

Comment: @LeoDabus Without `mountedVolumeURLs`I get a lot of irrelevant volumes (invisible ones) back so it's much better to use that option IMO

Comment: I said about the keys not the options

Comment: @LeoDabus Ah sorry I misread your comment. I didn’t notice the parameter was optional, thanks.